# Show/Hide TextInputLayout bottom stroke programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I want to show the `TextInputLayout` bottom stroke when there is at least one letter inside of the EditText, and hide it when there is no text.

I have tried looking up how to set `app:boxStrokeWidth` and `app:boxStrokeColor` programmatically, but could not find anything. I am using `onTextChangedListener` to check the input text length. Is this possible, or is there a workaround?

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count == 0) {
        // hide bottom stroke
    } else {
        // show bottom stroke
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't a method to hide/show. You can try using a FillexBox and use the `setBoxStrokeColor` method  applying a color selector with same color of the background box.

Comment: The issue with this is that when the focus changes, the color of the bottom stroke reverts back to its unfocused state color.

Comment: the `setBoxStrokeColor` can work with a selector and you can apply a color also for the unfocused state.

Comment: Ok thank you Gabriele, will give it a shot.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the 2 selectors I switch in between (for empty & filled EditTexts) work fine, except when I remove focus from the empty EditText, the bottom stroke still shows. I have tried using '<item android:state_focused="false" android:color="..."/>' but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas?